# How add margins/padding to a image:hover

Tags: html, css

What is the easy way to  place an image on top of text when they mouse over (hover) \

I was trying like this but it not working.

```
.nav-justified li:hover>a
{
    background:url(../images/circle-hover.png) center no-repeat;
    padding-bottom:-50px !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav id="topNav" role="navigation" aria-label="Top Navigation">
  <ul class="nav nav-justified">  
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</nav>  

  O (circle-hover)
 LINK
```

Comment: provide a fiddle or relevant please

Comment: `padding` can't be negative.

Answer (score 2):

Use a :pseudo-element for the `background-image` and give it a higher `z-index: 1`.

```
.nav-justified li:hover > a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(../images/circle-hover.png) center no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Demo:

```css
a {
  position: relative;
}
a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/30/10);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Comment: `padding` can't be negative.

Comment: @Oriol - Oops missed that one.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: @Jason - _"What is the easy way to place an image on top of text.....I was trying like this but it not working"_

Comment: OP is trying to overlaying with background-image when hovering the `a` some text, thats why this answers the question :)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py: My understanding is that the OP is trying to position a background image *above* text, hence the padding.  And you're wrong he doesn't *have* to set the display to block.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Thanks for you help, this work but the circle appear in the text not above, I update my question in which show what Im trying to do.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Whit that html is enough of you need the entire page,

Comment: @Ricardo - Not the entire page, just the html that is relevant to the CSS code you have posted in your question.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I modified my question, please check it.

Comment: @Ricardo - which circle are you talking about?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Is a little circle(jpg) that I wanto to use like a hover

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .hover. Make sure you replace ENTER URL HERE with the path to your image file.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(ENETR URL HERE)");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#FFF");
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>
<body>


  <div class="box">
    
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```